# How to Evaluate a Single-Value Prediction for a 6-Month Period Against Historical Data?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, forecasting, predictive-models, model-evaluation

I'm tackling a time-series forecasting issue with daily granularity, aiming to predict a single aggregate value that represents the total sum of incidents over a 6-month period. My approach involves aggregating the daily data into monthly totals. Consequently, the test set will encompass 6 months, and the final prediction will be the sum of these monthly totals, yielding a single predictive value for the test set. This allows for a comparison with the actual total value (y actual).

However, I'm questioning the practicality of evaluating the test set based on a single aggregate value. What metrics would be appropriate for this situation? Additionally, I'm seeking guidance on best practices for generating confidence intervals for such a single-value prediction to effectively quantify the uncertainty involved

Comment: Can you either collect more data, or run rolling simulations and evaluations?